# Gradle android application build failed with IntelliJ (java not found issue, but set correctly)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've problem with build my Android project from IntelliJ. I set up default Android project and try to compile, then:

> Error:
>   Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
> (...)
>
> /android-sdk/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx: line 89: exec: java: not found

I use gradle wrapper from ide. I have java on the PATH, and JAVA_HOME properly. So what is the reason of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem.

I've set my java on the path in .bashrc file. Probably dx runs from shell without read that file, so I set that in '/etc/profile' and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your using android. So you selected the Android API in "Project SDK" in File > Project Structure, and when you click on edit next to the android api, there is a java jdk selected?
Your build.gradle file should also contain

```
apply-plugin: 'android'
```

and your sourcedir must be set in sourcesets in your build.gradle:

```
srcDir 'src/java'
```

more info about getting started with gradle build-files can you find here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: Of course, I have choosen one, the same as on the PATH